# Stripe CardFeild Doesn't Work on Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-stripe

I have both the flutter_stripe and the flutter_stripe_web packages added to pubspec.yaml and payments works fine for Android using the `CardFeild` widget but for Web I always get the following error :

`You may test your Stripe.js integration over HTTP. However, live Stripe.js integrations must use HTTPS.`

and the payment fails, I have tested this on test mode and live mode and it doesnt work on both... for android it works on both!

also my website does have an https certificate but i am still getting the same error

Comment: Based on the error message, it seems like your webpage is not running on HTTPS, i.e. the checkout page should be in the URL of `https://...` when using live mode publishable key, e.g. `pk_live_xxx`. Can you double check if your checkout page is indeed running on HTTPS?